# Solving a linear system instead of doing Metropolis-Hasting, what is wrong?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, algorithms, markov-chains

I am reading about Metropolis-Hasting algortithm. The idea is that we are given a distribution $\pi$ and we want to construct a Markov chain $P_{ij}$ which has $\pi$ as an invariant distribution. As I understand, satisfying the detailed balance equation should be enough to ensure this. Now my question might be silly but couldn't we solve the following for the $P_{ij}'s$? :
\begin{align}
\pi_i P_{ij}=\pi_j P_{ji}\\
\sum_{j}P_{ij}=1\\
P_{ij}\ge 0
\end{align}

The solution would satisfy the detailed balance equation no? (and so $\pi$ would be an invariant distribution of it)

Comment: There are two issues with your approach: first of all, the system you describe does not have a unique solution. Second, the constraint $P_{ij} \geq 0$ means that this is no longer simply a linear system of equations; instead, we would need linear programming

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes, but couldn't we use the simplex method or something like that?

Comment: Sure, but is that easier than the usual method?

Comment: @BenGrossmann No but it seems more intuitive